# What does z-transform imply?

Tags: dsp-core, z-transform

As z tranform is the transformation of discrete time signals into complex frequency domian. What do you get out of complex Stuff. As wikipedia calls it complex frequency domain. Why do you need it ? 
How to look at it, In order to understand it from the text?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! This question is closed because it is why to broad for easy and complete answering.

Comment: I just asked for a simple explanation. If you are closing this question saying complex to answer. It will never be understood by many other who vists this site for informantion.

Comment: I'm not saying it's too complex to answer, I'm saying it's too broad: **textbooks** have been written to try to answer your question... which is why I suggest you read a textbook and ask more specific questions about what you don't understand or what you find puzzling.  BTW: I didn't close the question.  **Five** other members of the site did.  Please be more specific in what questions you ask in future. That's the way this site works. (-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's in the textbooks.

here's a short synopsis:

in continuous-time LTI systems, you have 3 fundamental classes of building blocks:

1. scaler (multiply signal by a constant)
2. adder (add signals)
3. integrator (integrate signal w.r.t. time)

the first two do not discriminate w.r.t. frequency.  so you can't build a "filter" out of just the first two because there is nothing in that filter that responds differently for different frequencies.  so you need the third class which we commonly use the label "$s^{-1}$" for.

for discrete-time LTI systems, the first two classes are the same as for continuous time.  you have scalers and adders.  but the third class of fundamental processing block is different.  the third class is a unit delay, a delay of one unit of discrete time and we call that "$z^{-1}$".  that's how digital filters know the difference between one frequency and another.

Comment: My text never explained anything clearly. Thanks for the time. I did understand from your answer.